# How to ask about another project within company?

Tags: interviewing, communication, job-search, united-states

I'm an employee at a Fortune 500 consulting company (*CompanyX*). I'm currently working on a project in NY.

I was going through *CompanyX's* website, and I saw another project that looked really interesting, but it's in California and unrelated to my current project.

My question: how can I ask about this other project without my local group knowing about it or thinking that I'm looking for work?

In theory, our director encourages us to talk to them about this kind of stuff, but I have a feeling that they'll think that I'm either not interested in my current job or, most likely, that I'm *job-hunting*.

I would like to apply to this new project within the company without my bosses knowing about it, but I'm not sure how to do this. If I did apply, they can easily search by name and state, and they'll find me... that info will spread to my local group.

Comment: Have your looked to see if your company has a policy on internal transfers?

Comment: The only thing I see as a potential problem if you want to get another project before your current one is completed. But that for your management to decide how replaceable you are.  Since you intend to stay employed by your current consulting company I do not believe that *job-hunting* even applies. Ii's more like *position* or *assignment* hunting.

Answer (score 3):

It's likely impossible for you to apply for this other position without your currently management knowing about it.  But there is nothing wrong with that.  Here's my take on this...

1. Your career is YOUR responsibility, not your company's.  Either they support you in that or they don't.  Either way, you want to know their practice on this.  A good company will support employee career growth (to the extent it's mutually beneficial) or they won't.  In the latter case the sooner you know that the better.
2. Something about this new position caught your attention.  Turn that into a "career growth" proposition.  A good manager and/or good company will support you and clearly it's their need (hence the posting).
3. If you find that they don't support such career moves, then it's time to start looking outside for a new position.

Answer (score 1):

Your feeling is is incorrect. People moving from project to project to follow their interests is a normal part of running a larger company. It doesn't mean they intend to slack off or quit; it means they're taking an interest in the company's larger goals and their career within it.

In fact, you probably *want* to inform your manager. They're going to be asked for their opinion of your skills anyway; it will probably help if they know why you're interested in the other group. Also, ideally, you'd want to schedule the move at a time which doesn't inconvenience your current group more than it must, which is another reason the managers need to work together to make the transfer happen.

If you have *specific* reasons to think that your current manager would object to your career development, that might be a different kettle of worms. In that case, I'd ask my second-line to help me make this happen.

Note that, depending on company policy, you may need to pay your own travel costs and use vacation time for an in-person offsite interview. If you really think this is likely to be a good move for you, that's a trivial investment.

Caveat: I was working in the US; practice in other countries may be different. On the other hand, I was working in one of the larger and more bureaucratic companies, so if anything I expect that for most folks it's even less hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Many companies encourage the development of existing assets, for many reasons, and you're one of them. As a person who wants to invest time and efforts to grow ***within*** the company, you'll probably be given more opportunities to succeed.

> Our director encourages us to talk to them about this kind of stuff

Do that. Talk to management. First, talk about your plans, what you want to do, achieve, ask for their feedback about what you could improve, or how you could do that. You want to be better, and what's good for you ***within*** the company is good ***for*** the company. It's a win-win situation. Forget about doing things in the back of people/management.

If they think it's not the right time for you to move, or that you're not the right person for this particular job, they'll not only (probably) tell you and explain, but they can also help you make other interesting plans, because you showed motivation and interest in being a better employee, which is good for them.

Doing that, in the US, the worst answer I ever got was: "*sorry, not possible*". Standard answer was: "*we'll think about it, and as soon as possible (say, 3-4 weeks at least), we'll give you a chance*". Means I had my chance a couple of months later. The kind of answer you usually get is based on many factors, two of them being what company needs, and what manager thinks of you and your job.

If you think you're a good fit for the job, prepare yourself for a talk with your manager, bring your reasoning and main points, give facts, and enlight the value/gain for all of you. Most companies have policies regarding internal moves, follow the rules.

Answer (score 0):

How you do this depends on two things:

- how the company handles internal transfers.
- how your management reacts to anybody leaving the project.

It is very possible for an individual manager to make a possible transition either easy or hard regardless of the company policy.

Good companies entourage employees to look outside their current position. They allow employees to apply for transfers without their current manager knowing. Having a well defined process for annual reviews helps the new project gather information, without having to interview your current manager or co-workers.

If your current manager will make things difficult the ability to be hired by the new project without your current manager finding out is very important.

Some companies don't have a good way to use stealth to facilitate internal transfers. They immediately reach out to your current project, and expose your disloyalty to the current project. Some managers are OK with this, others are not.

Before attempting to apply, research the company policies. Determine how internal transfers are handled. You may have to ask somebody who has recently transferred into your area. I wouldn't ask anybody in your current chain of command because you could expose your desire to leave before you are ready.

Note some companies have two different tracks for internal transfers. If it is initiated by the current employee or the new manger, it is hidden from the current management; but if the current project is ending then the process is not hidden so everybody can work together to find landing spots for all the employees.